# How to get a partial sum formula

Tags: calculus, summation

Let S denote sum from 1 to n of (k-1)/k! . I tried obtaining a partial sum formula, but I couldn't get too far. WolframAlpha comes with  quite a simple form, but I fail to see how they got there . Can anyone suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integer $k\ge1,$ $$\frac{k-1}{k!}=\frac k{k\cdot (k-1)!}-\frac1{k!}=\frac1{(k-1)!}-\frac1{k!}$$ which is the $k$th term of a [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{k-1}{k!} = \frac{1}{(k-1)!} - \frac{1}{k!}$$
So your sum is (this is a telescoping sum) $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{(k-1)!} - \frac{1}{k!}
\right) = \left(\frac{1}{0!} - \frac{1}{1!}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{1!} - \frac{1}{2!}\right) +  ... \left(\frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \frac{1}{n!}\right)  = 1 - \frac{1}{n!}$$